# Logitech G35 Headset volume wheel has more effect when used slowly

Tags: audio, scroll-wheel, logitech-headset

My headset has a volume wheel on the side, and when I slide it up or down quickly it changes the volume quite gradually: while watching the Logitech Gaming Software's headset tab, it takes about 16 fast swipes to get from 100 volume to 0.

Alternatively, if I swipe it slowly, I can get down to 0 volume in only 2 swipes. It takes less time for me to lower the volume this way.

I don't like this at all. I'd rather it be the obvious way of swiping quickly to quickly lower the volume, and swiping slowly to slowly lower the volume.

I've looked through the options in LGS and done some searches online but I can't find anyone else with this problem.

Are there any config changes I can make to fix this? Are there any possible 3rd party workarounds?